# How to remove a value from an entire column and past value in new column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use google app scripts to remove values from a column but I cannot find the correct method(s) for taking the values from each cell in a column searching them for a specific value, removing that value, and then returning the new values to the same column. Example

[image: google sheet with 12 rows and 3 columns 2nd column has values A1,A2,etc decending down rows]

I want to remove "A" from every cell in column 2 and paste the new values into the same range. To be specific I am trying to literally remove the letter A from a number.

Comment: I think that providing your current script will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the A1 Notation to select the column you want to edit.

```
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

let range = ss.getRange("B:B");
```

Use `.getValues()` to obtain the rows of the selected column.

Then map the values in the rows using the String function `.slice()`.

```
let rows = range.getValues();

// In this case i will slice from the 1st index since you want to remove the 1st letter.  
let edited_rows = rows.map(row => [row[0].slice(1)]);
```

Please mind how I wrapped the return value of my map function in an array. This is because i want my `edited_rows` array to be 2 dimensional.

In this way i can replace the rows in the selected columns directly with the function `.setValues()`.

```
range.setValues(edited_rows);
```

### References:

[Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

[Javascript slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)